# how to upgrade a phonegap plugin from 1.6.x to 2.7?

Tags: android, cordova

The code is aim for grap content by using jsoup, and i'm try to upgrade the code

Here is my code so far:

```
package com.phonegap.g7.plugin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class UrlFeedJava extends CordovaPlugin {
    //@Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        PluginResult r=null;
        try
        {
            String target = data.getString(0);
            String selector = data.getString(1);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(target).get();
            Element masthead = doc.select(selector).first();
            String content=masthead.toString();
            String title = doc.title();
            r=new PluginResult(status,content);
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            System.out.print("ee:"+ee.getMessage());
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

the PhonegapPlugin.js file

```
UrlFeed.prototype = {
        send: function(success, error, url, selector){
            cordova.exec(success, error, "UrlFeedJava", "send", [url, selector]);
        }
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin('urlfeed', new UrlFeed());
});
```

the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <script type='text/javascript'  src='jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='cordova-2.7.0.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'  src='PhonegapPlugin.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        var onSend = function(){

            var success = function(data){
                $('#show').html(data);
            };

            var error = function(e){
                alert(e);
            };        
            var url = 'http://sports.163.com/12/0618/09/8496QLNG00051C8V.html';
            var selector = $('#selector').val();
            window.plugins.urlfeed.send(success, error, url, selector);
        };
        $('#send').bind('click', onSend);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='messageDiv'>
    <input type='text' id='selector'></input>
    <div id='show'></div>
    <button type='button' id='send'>Send Me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Especially i don't understand the function of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With newer phonegap releases you define the constructor in javascript like this:

```
var UrlFeed = function(){};

cordova.addConstructor(function() {
    if (!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }
    window.plugins.UrlFeed = new UrlFeed();
});
```

It makes the urlfeed object available to your entire application, you access it anywhere like

```
window.plugins.UrlFeed.doSomething();
```

Adding methods to your plugin:

```
UrlFeed.prototype.doSomething = function(arguments){
    //do stuff

    //send to phonegap
    return PhoneGap.exec(
        successCallback,    
        failureCallback,     
        'UrlFeed', 
        null,              
        [arguments]        
    );
};
```

You have to change your java plugin like this:

```
public class UrlFeedJava extends CordovaPlugin {
    //@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args,
        final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        //your code
        return true;
    }
}
```

So basic change is that you do not return a plugin result anymore, but a simple boolean. So remove all plugin result code from your java code.

Please have a look at the simple toast plugin. It shows you how a phonegap plugin is developed https://github.com/giver/cordova-android-toast-plugin

Ref: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: thanks, i'm another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348751/how-to-return-a-array-or-other-collections-elements-type-from-phonegap-android-p