# How to return a array or other collections elements type from phonegap android plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova

here is a part of my testing code in a java plugin (**i'm using phonegap 2.7**).

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

  try {

      String[] result;
      result = new String[10];
      result[0] = "test1 success";
      result[1] = "test2 success";
      callbackContext.success(result);  //error

  } catch(Exception ee) {
      System.out.print("ee:"+ee.getMessage());
  }
  return true;
}
```

My questions are :

1. how to return the array from android phonegap plugin so i can get the array in the javascript?
2. which data type is better than array (JSONArray?) to be returned?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**PluginResult** class is your friend:

```
public PluginResult(Status status, JSONObject message) {
    this.status = status.ordinal();
    this.message = (message != null) ? message.toString(): "null";
}
```

or

```
public PluginResult(Status status, String message) {
    this.status = status.ordinal();
    this.message = JSONObject.quote(message);
}
```

In your case it accepts either a json object or a string. So to return a json array you need

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("foo", "bar");

callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, json));
```